# Properly displaying cropped images in iOS v5.0.1 and below + ALAssetLibrary

Tags: iphone, crop, alasset

I am trying to display photos from the camera roll within my application using ALAssetLibrary. All images are displaying fine except for cropped images. ALAsset returns unedited version of the image when using `fullResolutionImage` method of `ALAssetRepresentation`instead of cropped version.
So I am trying to extract cropping information for `ALAsset` objects from its metadata. I googled for it and 've found that the cropping information is contained in the `AdjustmentXMP` key of metadata on my `ALAssetRepresentation` object. Using above info I am able to display cropped images correctly within my app but the approach on v5.1 and above but fails on iOS v5.0.
Meta data dictionary for a cropped image on iOS 5.1:

```
 {
    AdjustmentXMP = "<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x=\"adobe:ns:meta/\" x:xmptk=\"XMP Core 4.4.0\">\n   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\">\n      <rdf:Description rdf:about=\"\"\n            xmlns:aas=\"http://ns.apple.com/adjustment-settings/1.0/\">\n         <aas:AffineA>1</aas:AffineA>\n         <aas:AffineB>0</aas:AffineB>\n         <aas:AffineC>0</aas:AffineC>\n         <aas:AffineD>1</aas:AffineD>\n         <aas:AffineX>-266</aas:AffineX>\n         <aas:AffineY>-589</aas:AffineY>\n         <aas:CropX>0</aas:CropX>\n         <aas:CropY>0</aas:CropY>\n         <aas:CropW>270</aas:CropW>\n         <aas:CropH>162</aas:CropH>\n      </rdf:Description>\n   </rdf:RDF>\n</x:xmpmeta>\n";
    ColorModel = RGB;
    DPIHeight = 72;
    DPIWidth = 72;
    Depth = 8;
    Orientation = 1;
    PixelHeight = 1024;
    PixelWidth = 768;
    "{Exif}" =     {
        ApertureValue = "2.526069";
        BrightnessValue = "0.1544926";
        ColorSpace = 1;
        ComponentsConfiguration =         (
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        );
        DateTimeDigitized = "2013:01:22 14:12:59";
        DateTimeOriginal = "2013:01:22 14:12:59";
        ExifVersion =         (
            2,
            2
        );
        ExposureMode = 0;
        ExposureProgram = 2;
        ExposureTime = "0.06666667";
        FNumber = "2.4";
        Flash = 16;
        FlashPixVersion =         (
            1,
            0
        );
        FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 33;
        FocalLength = "4.13";
        ISOSpeedRatings =         (
            400
        );
        MeteringMode = 5;
        PixelXDimension = 768;
        PixelYDimension = 1024;
        SceneCaptureType = 0;
        SensingMethod = 2;
        ShutterSpeedValue = "3.906905";
        SubjectArea =         (
            1631,
            1223,
            881,
            881
        );
        WhiteBalance = 0;
    };
    "{GPS}" =     {
        Altitude = "216.1379";
        AltitudeRef = 0;
        DateStamp = "2013:01:22";
        Latitude = "28.46366666666667";
        LatitudeRef = N;
        Longitude = "77.04916666666666";
        LongitudeRef = E;
        TimeStamp = "08:42:56.00";
    };
    "{TIFF}" =     {
        DateTime = "2013:01:22 14:14:39";
        Make = Apple;
        Model = "iPhone 5";
        Orientation = 1;
        ResolutionUnit = 2;
        Software = "QuickTime 7.7.1";
        XResolution = 72;
        YResolution = 72;
        "_YCbCrPositioning" = 1;
    };
}
```

Meta data dictionary for a cropped image on iOS 5.0.1:

```
Metadata: {
    ColorModel = RGB;
    Depth = 8;
    PixelHeight = 2048;
    PixelWidth = 1078;
    "{JFIF}" =     {
        DensityUnit = 0;
        JFIFVersion =         (
            1,
            1
        );
        XDensity = 1;
        YDensity = 1;
    };
}
```

As you see above metadata dictionary on v5.1 contains `AdjustmentXMP` which contains cropping information while the same dictionary on v5.0 doesn't have `AdjustmentXMP` key. So the cropping fails on v5.0.1.

Any pointers as to how to display cropped images on devices with iOS v5.0.1 and below ?